# Hibernate Criteria - Joining on un-mapped entity

Tags: java, hibernate, criteria-api

Given 2 tables

```
@Entity
@Table
public class SomeEntity {
    @Id
    private Long someId;

    @Column
    private String text;

    @ManyToMany
    @JoinTable(name = "map", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "someId"), inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "eventId")) 
    private Set<SomeEntityEvent> events;

    // get/set
}
```

and

```
@Entity
@Table
public class SomeEntityEvent {
    @Id
    private Long eventId;

    @Column
    private Calendar date;

    // get/set
}
```

Hibernate will generate the following tables (notice I don't have an entity for Map)

> ```
> some_entity: someId | text 
> some_entity_event: eventId | date
> map: someId | eventId
> ```

I want to use the `Criteria` API to get all `SomeEntityEvent` instances that belong to a certain `SomeEntity` ordered by date and within some range. With SQL, I could simply do

```
SELECT * 
FROM some_entity_event e
NATURAL JOIN map
WHERE map.someId = [ my field ]
ORDER BY e.date DESC
LIMIT 0, 100;
```

Since I don't have a `Map` entity (or a reference to `SomeEntity`), I don't know how to build a `Criteria` that is equivalent to the query above. The criteria below gets me all `SomeEntityEvent`. I want only those that belong to some `SomeEntity`.

```
Criteria criteria = getCurrentSession().createCriteria(SomeEntityEvent.class);
criteria.addOrder(Order.desc("date"))
    .setFirstResult(firstResult)
    .setMaxResults(maxResults);
return criteria.list();
```

Is this possible with `Criteria`? If yes, how do you perform that join?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, start with HQL. Criteria is useful when a query must be composed dynamically, based on a set of... criteria. Even if you absolutely want to use the criteria API, having the HQL query and translate it is easier.

OK, so you want the events that belong to a certain SomeEntity ordered by date and within some range:

```
select event from SomeEntity entity
join entity.events event
where entity.id = :entityId
and event.date between :startDate and :endDate
order by event.date
```

Now you can translate it to criteria. The problem is that the criteria API doesn't allow selecting any other entity than the root entity, and since you don't have an association going from SomeEntityEvent to SomeEntity, you're stuck.

My advice would thus be: do it in HQL, or make the association bidirectional. If it is bidirectional, you can write the HQL query like this:

```
select event from SomeEntityEvent event
join event.entities entity
where entity.id = :entityId
and event.date between :startDate and :endDate
order by event.date
```

And it can easily be translated to criteria:

```
Criteria c = session.createCriteria(SomeEntityEvent.class, "event");
c.createAlias("event.entities", "entity");
c.add(Restrictions.eq("entity.id", entityId);
c.add(Restrictions.between("event.date", startDate, endDate);
c.addOrder("event.date");
```

Note how every part of the HQL query directly translates to a similar criteria instruction.

Comment: I think I'm going to end up adding the bidirectional association. I didn't originally because I didn't want users to be able to follow that association. I was looking at some other questions where you give the same answer, except, at the end, you set the `ResultTransformer` to `DistinctRootEntityResultTransformer.INSTANCE`. What's that about?

Comment: Also, in the first HQL option, does the 'join' perform like a `natural join`, only mapping equal ids?

Comment: It avoids having the same event several times in the result. It's basically identical to having a `select distinct` in HQL. You might indeed need this. Forgot about it.

Comment: Yes. The join uses the mapping information you specified on the association. So it uses the join table and the join columns you specified.